# enumerate instances within queryset by group

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model which can be subdivided into groups

```
Gender:   Class:  Item

M           1       1

F           2       2

M           1       3

M           2       4
```

if I make a queryset in Django from this model, is there a compact way to annotate it with a kind of a 'counter' within each group?
so if I do a query:

```
q = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('class','gender')
```

the result would be:

```
Gender:   Class:  Item  Counter (Id in Class)

M           1       1     1

M           1       3     2

F           2       2     1

M           2       4     2
```

Comment: Hold on, what is `Item`? Does it occur multiple times?

Comment: ah, sorry, just a unique identifier throughout the model ('pk')

Comment: but then how can it occur multiple times?

Comment: it doesn't. And in this example it doesn't either: it is a set of [1, 2, 3, 4]